# Could not find gem 'refinerycms-disqus (~> 0.0.1) - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, disqus

I'm Trying to install disqus comments for RefineryCMS-products, first i'm following the steps of [Github](https://github.com/keram/refinerycms-disqus) , but to add the line gem `'refinerycms-disqus', '~> 0.0.1'` to the gemfile and run `bundle install` I get this error `Could not find gem 'refinerycms-disqus (~> 0.0.1) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem`

The version of my RefineryCMS is 3-0-stable and the version of my rails is 4.2.7.1

This is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :jruby]
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bourbon'
gem 'neat'
gem 'meta-tags', '~> 2.0.0'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'dragonfly-s3_data_store'
end

group :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'refinerycms', git: 'https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'quiet_assets', group: :development

# Add support for searching inside Refinery's admin interface.
gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed', ['~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.0']

# Add support for Refinery's custom fork of the visual editor WYMeditor.
gem 'refinerycms-wymeditor', ['~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.6']

# The default authentication adapter
gem 'refinerycms-authentication-devise', '~> 1.0'

gem 'mailchimp-api', require: 'mailchimp'
gem 'disqus_rails'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'refinerycms-blog', git: 'https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog', branch: 'master'
gem 'puma'
gem 'refinerycms-disqus', '~> 0.0.1'

gem 'refinerycms-productos', path: 'vendor/extensions'
```

this is the complete log after run bundle install

```
C:\Sites\ifurniture>bundle install
Your Gemfile lists the gem rails_12factor (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of
 just one of them later.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'refinerycms-disqus (~> 0.0.1)' in any of the gem sources
listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
```

Comment: does it work when you do `gem 'refinerycms-disqus'` without the version number?

Comment: It does not work, I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gem 'refinerycms-disqus', github: 'keram/refinerycms-disqus'` should do the trick.

Comment: The error changes for this
`Could not find gem 'refinerycms-core (~> 2.718.0.dev)', which is required by gem

'refinerycms', in any of the sources.`

Comment: @iFurniture When using gem sources from git, you often need to manually track down the correct dependency versions from git too. Your life will be much easier if you try to stick to published gems from https://rubygems.org.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but the gem 'refinerycms-disqus' no appears in rubygems.org.

Comment: agreed with @HolgerJust.  That said, you could try `gem 'refinerycms-core', github: 'refinery/refinerycms'`.  You may need to comment out your 'refinerycms-discus' line, run bundle, then add back in 'refinerycms-discus'